# Android parse insertion

Tags: android, parse-platform, insert

I tried running this code below and, runs perfectly without any error and toast saved; but when I go check Parse database it doesn't display the value which I tried to insert.

```
Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    rest_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    food_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    food_price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                    review = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                    float price= Float.parseFloat(food_price.getText().toString());
                    //ParseObject res = new ParseObject("Restaurant");
                    ParseObject.registerSubclass(Restaurant.class);
                    ParseObject res = ParseObject.create("Restaurant");
                    res.put("latitude", lat);
                    res.put("longitude", longi);
                    res.put("restaurant_name", rest_name.getText().toString());
                    res.put("food_name", food_name.getText().toString());
                    res.put("food_price",price);
                    res.put("review", review.getText().toString());
                    res.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use this code:

```
    ParseObject r = new ParseObject("Restaurant");
    // add the other values
    r.put("id", id);
    r.put("name", name);
    r.put("foodname", foodname);
    r.saveInBackground();
```

Also check if `e` is `null` in the done callback. If it's not `null` there is an exception.

Answer (score -1):

Not the above code:

this code

```
Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    rest_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    food_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    food_price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                    review = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                    float price= Float.parseFloat(food_price.getText().toString());
                    //ParseObject res = new ParseObject("Restaurant");
                    ParseObject.registerSubclass(Restaurant.class);
                    ParseObject res = ParseObject.create("Restaurant");
                    res.put("latitude", lat);
                    res.put("longitude", longi);
                    res.put("restaurant_name", rest_name.getText().toString());
                    res.put("food_name", food_name.getText().toString());
                    res.put("food_price",price);
                    res.put("review", review.getText().toString());
                    res.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Delete this answer, I added this code to your question. :) Welcome to SO!

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must create this type of ParseObject using ParseObject.create() or the proper subclass.